# Autohotkey, issue after mapping capslock::ctrl

Tags: autohotkey

How would you remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd> (Up) consistently?
Here is what I tried:

```
capslock::ctrl
^p::send {up}
```

While holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> this sends <kbd>↑</kbd> the first time,
but then <kbd>P</kbd> unless I release <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then press it again.

I found that it also happens with something like this:

```
OriginKey::DestinationKey
*DestinationKey & normalKey::maptoAnother
```

Without releasing the artificial modifier it keeps inserting `normalKey` NOT `maptoAnother`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using:

```
capslock::ctrl
^p::send ^{up}
```

`{blind}` can also be used in this case, because it avoids releasing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>

```
^p::send {blind}{up}
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't directly answer your question, but willwillis suggested [XKeymacs](http://www.cam.hi-ho.ne.jp/oishi/indexen.html) for making Emacs-emulating key bindings in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11973968/how-can-i-remap-ctrl-x-ctrl-c-in-autohotkey).

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you're using a program where ^Up != Up :

```
^p::SendPlay {Up}
```

I think you can also specify the mode for send once and use send after that :

```
SendMode Play
^p::Send {Up}
```

I think this is a better solution as you can directly send whatever key you want and are not forced to send ^ as with {Blind}.