# How can I remap CTRL-x CTRL-c in Autohotkey?

Tags: autohotkey

Having recently moved to Emacs (and become a fanboy), I'd like to use Autohotkey to make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> a universal "Close" command.

Here's what I have in my `.ahk` file:

```
; Universal Close
:*:^x^c::
    WinClose, A
    Return
```

which doesn't appear to work. What am I doing wrong?

---

To clarify my keystrokes, here is the sequence:

1. Hold down the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key
2. Press and release the <kbd>X</kbd> key
3. Press and release the <kbd>C</kbd> key
4. Release the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key

On either pressing or releasing the <kbd>C</kbd> key (I don't mind which), the active window is closed.

---

Success story: I have implemented the answer by [Honest Abe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1217270/honest-abe), adding a small tweak to avoid annoyance when actually using Emacs itself. Here's the end result (thanks, H.A.!):

```
; Universal Close
$^x::
    IfWinActive, ahk_class Emacs
        Sendinput, ^x
    Else {
        keywait, c, d, t0.6
        If ErrorLevel
            Sendinput, ^x
        Else 
            WinClose, A
        }
    Return
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example that waits 0.6 seconds for <kbd>C</kbd> to be pressed after <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>:

```
$^x::
keywait, c, d, t0.6
If ErrorLevel
    Sendinput, ^x
Else 
    WinClose, A
Return
```

If <kbd>C</kbd> is not pressed within 0.6 seconds <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> is sent.
`$` is used at the very beginning when a hotkey sends itself (to avoid an infinite loop).

Manual references:
[$](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)
[keywait](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/commands/KeyWait.htm)

Comment: @HonestAbe listed code doesn't work with non-English keyboard layouts. First line `$^x` works well, but `keywait` function accepts wrong character and fails. Don you know how to fix it?

Comment: @VasiliyKevroletin My first thoughts are make sure you have the latest version from http://ahkscript.org/ ... and make sure you are saving as UTF-8.

Comment: Saving to UTF-8 with BOM helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While this isn't a direct answer to your question, you may want to look at XKeymacs if you haven't already, http://www.cam.hi-ho.ne.jp/oishi/indexen.html

It gives you ALOT of Emacs functionality within all/most windows apps. As with Emacs it is highly configurable, so you can enable/disable Emacs bindings on a global or application level.

It may not be the right solution for everyone, but I can't live without it.