# AHK Macro only executes once when using remapped control - always executes when using normal control key

Tags: macros, autohotkey, remap

I have a few key mappings and macros I use via AutoHotkey.
I have remapped control to capslock and I made a macro that lets me press ^, for home and ^. for end. This works perfectly fine if I press capslock and ',' or '.' once. But if I continue to hold down capslock and then press ',' or '.' again it just inserts the character. I get the expected behavior when I hold down the actual capslock key.

I've tried the suggestions from the answer in this question: [Autohotkey, issue after mapping capslock::ctrl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9560923/autohotkey-issue-after-mapping-capslockctrl)
and that works -- except it changes the behavior from start/end of line to start/end of file.

Here is my code:

```
^,::Send, {Home}
^.::Send, {End}
Capslock::Ctrl
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible complications when directly mapping <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to a key.  I would suggest you go the route of setting a variable when <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> is held down. Here is how I would suggest you do it for AutoHotkey_L.

```
global capDown = 0

CapsLock::
    capDown = 1
return

CapsLock up::
    capDown = 0
return


#If capDown
    *h::CapsNav("Left")
    *j::CapsNav("Down")
    *k::CapsNav("Up")
    *l::CapsNav("Right")

    *,::CapsNav("Home")
    *.::CapsNav("End")

    *n::CapsNav("Home", "^")
    *p::CapsNav("End", "^")

    *a::Send ^a ; add as needed



CapsNav(action, initmod = "", mod = "+")
{
    If ! GetKeyState("alt")
        Send % initmod "{" action "}"
    Else
        Send % mod . initmod "{" action "}"
    SetCapsLockState, AlwaysOff
}
```

For the recent version of AutoHotkey remove `global` and change `#If capDown` to `if (capDown)`

The included function also allows <kbd>Alt</kbd> to be held down to select text while moving.  It also allows a modifier such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> to be used.

If you use <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> for other key combinations, you will want to add all of those as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: This looks very interesting and I would like to use it. I love that you included VI keybindings, I've never thought of doing that but it's brilliant. However when trying to run this script I get this error:
``Line Text: global capDown = 0``
``Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.``

Comment: It sounds like you may be running AHK Standard as opposed to AHK_L. The `global` is not required for the script to work correctly.  Try removing it and see if that works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that says:
``Line Text: #If capDown Error: This line does not contain a recognized action.``

Comment: It looks like the `#If` command is not supported in AutoHotkey Standard.  [Here is the link](http://ahkscript.org/) to the site for AHK_L.  Download and install that, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I found out how to enable this functionality in the current AHK release and suggested an edit to @ElliotDeNolf's post.

Comment: Great to hear you got it to work @IanElletson. Be sure to accept the answer if it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have this behaviour.

I tried this to test and it works fine multiple times with both Ctrl or CapsLock pressed all the time.

```
Capslock::Ctrl
^,::SoundBeep, 300, 500
^.::SoundBeep, 1000, 500
```

Comment: Interesting. I have the stated behavior on two distinct computers.

Comment: Could it be a version issue, I use AutoHotkey v1.1.10.01. Or is there something else, e.g. your OS version or keyboard driver.